# How do I edit HTML5 tags in Dreamweaver cs6

Tags: html5, dreamweaver

In Dreamweaver CS6 you can simply right click and "edit tag" to see the beginning and end points of that tag. But I get a greyed out "Edit tag" option when its any HTML5 tag such as nav, section, header etc. How can I fix this?

Comment: I was also having the same problem. I could not find a solution for it.So what i did is i went to design view and will click on the document and will search for the tags coming on the bottom bar of DW. So then i will click the section on that and go to the code view to see the closing and ending of the tag. eg:section

Answer (score 2):

1. Start Dreamweaver and go to **Edit** > **Tag Library Editor**
2. Click on the plus “+” icon and select **New Tag Library**
3. Give your new tag library a name, something like “HTML5 tags”
4. Select the type of documents you want the HTML5 tags to be used in from the “**Used in**“ list
5. Now, click on the plus “+” icon again and select **New Tags** this time
6. Type the HTML5 tags you’d like to add
    **TIP: add multiple tags at once** – copy and paste this selection of tags if you like:

   ```
   article, aside, audio, canvas,  command, datagrid, datalist, details, dialog, figure, footer, header, hgroup, mark, meter, nav, output, progress, rp, rt, ruby, section, source, time, video
   ```
7. Next, you can add HTML5 global attributes to these tags. Click on the plus “+” icon and select **Add Attributes**
8. Select the HTML5 tags library you created before  and select the tag you want to give attributes to. You can comfortably add the global  attributes to all new HTML5 tags:

   ```
   class, id, style, contenteditable, irrelevant, tabindex, contextmenu, lang, template, dir, ref, title, draggable, registrationmark
   ```

   However [check](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html) to see if any specific tag attributes should be added too …and click OK.
9. Once that is done you can also assign attribute types where possible, ie: class = CssStyle or dir = Enumerator (with values: ltr, rtl) etc.
10. That’s it!

reference: http://www.creativeworld.com.au/blog/web-development/adding-html5-tags-to-dreamweaver-cs4/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have these in my library. These instructions are fine when writing a new tag and it automatically creates the end tag, but my issue is different. When I right click and attempt to "edit tag" any html5 tag its greyed out. Any ideas?